# How to test if a, in circuit, complementary darling transistor is still functioning properly?

Tags: resistance, troubleshooting, darlington

I think a transistor broke down. My knowledge of electronics is not sufficient to solve my issue, so it seems. Hopefully some better educated mind can help me on this.

This question is about troubleshooting a PWM signal to a fan of [this board](http://reprap.org/mediawiki/images/7/74/Arduino_MEGA_Ultimaker_Shield_v1.5.4.brd) (Eagle file) from Arduino pin 7 to Transistor Q4 to PWM terminal. Below is the piece of the schematics its about:
[image: Arduino pin 7 via 1Kohm to BD679]

**Background info (not required to read though):**
I've got this PCB (Ultimaker 1.5.4 from 3D printer) and I think I short circuited a fan output. It is a couple of years ago already it happened. So I am not 100% sure, I hooked up an external power supply to power the fan instead. But now I want to have the fan driven by the PCB again and not by the external power source (as the software sometimes lowers the speed or turns of the fan completely, depending on what is printed). Anyway, currently it is not working to drive the fan by the PCB. It is driven by an Arduino Mega 2560 by a PWM (so says the PCB) through a BD679 FROM ST, which apparently is a complementary darlington transistor. I've only got some experience with MOSFETs and known that when the gate is driven by a voltage too high, the resistance between some pins become practically 0, meaning it broke down. Or they just exploded and it was very obvious what broke down.

**Info of measurement:**
Looking at [this datasheet.](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/1f/51/a4/6a/68/84/45/a6/CD00000939.pdf/files/CD00000939.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000939.pdf) and a multimeter I read the following on the pins of the BD679.
Resistance
E-C=unlimited
C-B=unlimited
E-B=9.19kOhm

**EDIT:**
With the diode test function I measure the following always starting with negative left, positive right:

- E-C=1 (no read out)
- E-B=1269
- C-B=906
- C-E=768
- B-E=1 (no read out)
- B-C=1 (no read out)

**Question:**
Do you think that these are normal readings for this complementary darling transistor?

EDIT 2:
I have tested the Arduino+PCB with an oscilloscope. While setup, I could send a GCODE to drive the PWM responsible to drive the fan. I see that the PWM signal at the Arduino (port 7) is correct, its duty cycle corresponds to what was commanded, and is 5V. The PWM pin of the Arduino to the transistor is connected with a 1Kohm resistor. The same duty cycle signal is found at the Base of the transistor at 1.28v. This I understand. And also at the Collector of the transistor at 960mv, this I do not understand. The signal at the Collector has the same frequency and duty cycle as the signal on the Base of the transistor. The emitter is equal to GND, which I understand. Now when I measure the PWM port that would be connected to a (12v fan) I measure 19.6v, the same as the power supply. The negative terminal of the fan connection shows the 960mv which is equal to the Collector of the transistor. That it is equal to the connector of the transistor I understand as it is directly connected. When I connect a 24vdc fan to the terminal it is not spinning. Although I measure 19.6v on the positive lead and the 960mv PWM signal on the negative lead of the terminal. Can I conclude that the transistor broke down because it is not sinking any current anymore?

Thank you.

Comment: Briefly, to answer your "resistance" question, you need a multi-meter that will forward bias a semiconductor junction.  This ranges from applying 0.3 to 0.7 volts across the junction before it turns on.  (Check to see if there is a Diode test setting on your multi-meter.)  Not until then will you know if the junction is still intact.  But, in the end, it is difficult to work out if a transistor is functioning normally with only a multi-meter.

Comment: Use the diode test function of your meter, not the resistance range.

Comment: @user287001 I've added a picture.

Comment: @st2000 Thanks for the technical info about how the measurement works.

Comment: @Felthry Just added the measurements.

Comment: At first glance, that does seem to be intact. No guarantees though. Your ordering of the terminals (as you put it, negative left and positive right) is the inverse of the conventional order, by the way; the positive side is the first one written in every engineering text I've ever seen.

Comment: @Felthry Could you please elaborate on how you come to the conclusion? I'm looking at the IC of the transistor but I don't quiet understand what the readings are telling me (or better, you).

Comment: Can you examine the signal going to the base of the transistor with the oscilloscope? Also, the [documentation](http://reprap.org/wiki/Ultimaker%27s_v1.5.4_PCB#Specifications) appears to say that a regulated 12 V is supplied for a fan and a PWM output is for LEDs/other lighting.

Comment: What that's telling me is that the internal diode junctions of your transistor are intact. The numbers you see are in millivolts, and are the forward voltage of the junctions. When the junctions are forward biased, you expect a voltage drop of roughly 0.6~0.7 volts across the junction. These values may vary as the transistor is not optimized for diode-like characteristics, but something in the ballpark is a good sign. Since it's an NPN darlington transistor, you expect one diode junction between base and collector (your C-B measurement), two diode junctions between base and emitter (E-B) and

Comment: one diode junction between emitter and collector, as the datasheet indicates there is a reverse protection diode internal to the device. Your base-collector diode is a bit high, but as I mentioned, you can't expect a transistor to perform very well as a diode and the values may change. If any of these showed overrange (i.e. read as "1" on your meter), indicating they are not conducting, or if any of them showed anything _other_ than overrange when measured in reverse, indicating they are conducting in the reverse direction, then the device would be deemed broken.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you for your comment. The signal you mentioned is for continuous cooling of the electronics I assume. That is not the signal that I am having trouble with. I did some oscilloscope measurements, see edit2 of the post.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk Please would you edit your question to add a circuit diagram of how the transistor and fan are connected, with appropriate voltages labelled.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I added a link to the Eagle PCB/Schematics file and also added an image of the piece of the circuitry its about.

Comment: "When I connect a 24vdc fan to the terminal it is not spinning. Although I measure 19.6v on the positive lead and the 960mv PWM signal on the negative lead of the terminal." - what is the voltage between Collector and Emitter of the transistor when the fan is connected?